# Detect entity framework datacontext changes for save/cancel enabled

Tags: entity-framework, data-binding, mvvm, datacontext

I'd like to detect if my entity framework datacontext has changed (has changes to apply with SaveChanges()) so I can bind it to my Save button IsEnabled. I know there is also CanExecute for my commands but I haven't used that yet. Whatever way - I'd like to enable my Save button when data changes are made by the user and disable if no changes have been made yet (i.e. straight after SaveChanges()).

Thanks

Comment: "detect of my datacontext has changed" - do you mean that your view.DataContext has changed or your EF DataContext changed?

Comment: Context will never change without your action so you should further specify what you expect.

Comment: My DataContext will change by user action (changing TwoWay binding values in the UI). Elaborated my original question.